# ArrayList: How to arraylist.set when you have multiple setters

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I currently have 2 classes. My bot:

```
public class Bot {
    private int X;
    private int Y;
    private int degress;

    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    public int getDegress() {
        return degress;
    }

    public void setX(int X) {
        this.X = X;
    }

    public void setY(int Y) {
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}
```

and my main code..
the problem i am having is when trying to set the degrees in my main class.
What I am trying to do is something similar to:

```
bots.set(bots.get(1).getDegress(),+1);
```

but gives me this error "The method set(int, Bot) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"

and how my ArrayList looks like

```
public static ArrayList<Bot> bots = new ArrayList<Bot>();
```

So to sum it up. How could i come about to change X, Y or Degress with the bots.set?

Comment: Do you want to increase the degrees with 1? Because then change `bots.set(bots.get(1).getDegress(),+1);` to `bots.set(bots.get(1).getDegress()+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bots.set(bots.get(1).getDegress(),+1);` at this line you are calling the Set method of ArrayList class, which is used to replace an element at the specified index in the list. It takes 2 parameters, first the index of the element to be replaced and 2nd the element to be replaced with. So in your case an `int` and an instance of `Bot` class.

To set `degrees` in you `Bot` class object you'll first have to get it from the `list bots` and use `setDegrees()` on the object of bot class(which btw seems to be missing from your Bot class).

```
bots.get(1).setDegrees(bots.get(1).getDegress()+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`bots.set` is an `ArrayList` method. To mutate a `Bot` instance, you must call a `Bot` method.

It should be:

```
Bot bot = bots.get(1);
bot.setDegrees(bot.getDegrees()+1);
```

Or course, you'll need a `setDegrees` method in your `Bot` class.

Comment: Alright thanks! and yeah i got one already forgot to include it.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Gave me this error "The method getDegrees() is undefined for the type ArrayList<Bot>"

Comment: @KappaCoder please notice it's `bot.getDegrees()`, not `bots.getDegrees()`